# How to use specific Date as the delay in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

I want to show an image in a specific date and time, without any actions from user, no refreshing of page.

Thanks.

Comment: where do you want to use?

Comment: Welcome to SO. please read the [tour] to get an Idea on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use localStorage to achieve this.
you can paste the code in your console, it will work.

```js
(function(){
  //somewhere in your code to set showPicTime
  var time = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 10000);
  localStorage.setItem("showPicTime", time)
  
  //when page loads get showPicTime form localStorage
  var showPicTime = new Date(localStorage.getItem("showPicTime")).getTime();
  var pollingHandler = setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    if(showPicTime - now < 0){
      console.log("Show picture");
      //kill the loop
      clearInterval(pollingHandler);
    }
  }, 1000);

}())
```

Answer (score 2):

call function on the specified date using setTimeout can be set this way

```
var alertDate = new Date("March 22, 2017 15:20:00").getTime(),
   onloadDate = Date.now(),
         tOut = alertDate - onloadDate;

tOut > 0
    ? setTimeout(()=>{ console.log('ok') }, tOut )
    : console.log('already past');
```

methods to set `new Date` watch to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
in contrast to the `setInterval` does not check for values of each time period, only timer works.
Max delay timeout/interval value = `0x7FFFFFFF` = `24day 20h 31m 23s 647ms` so if you want to call function, example, in the next year, you can combine setInterval with a large period and setTimeout

Comment: "Code only" - could you please explain why this is a good alternate solution?

Comment: first: is the answer to use a delay using setTimeout, secondly: in contrast to the setInterval does not check for values of each time period, only timer works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setInterval` to check the date periodically and if the date is right - display the image. Here is some simple **pseudo** code:

```
var dateToDisplayImageOn = new Date(...);
setInterval(function() {
   if(dateToDisplayImageOn == today) {
       displayImage();
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is not going to work. You are comparing two object references with each other, not two strings. The condition will always be false. `new Date() === new Date() // false`

Comment: As I mention in my answer - this is pseudo code and not supposed to work by just copy-paste. Comparing dates is outside of the question's scope.

Comment: I got it. I asked a very wrong question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an solution

```
var showDate = new Date("March 22, 2017 15:46:00");
var thisDate = new Date();
if(showDate == thisDate) {
 // code for showing picture
};
```

With a interval you could check every so much time, if the statement is true